# How to execute query in Drupal 7 block - through content editor (PHP CODE)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Can anyone explain to me how to execute a database query in Drupal 7 block? Block is not created from a module. It is created by admin. We have a PHP code filter in the content editor. There I have to execute a query.

Someone give me samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation and examples for writing db queries in Drupal are here: [Database abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7).

That said, it is not recommended to use the PHP filter and enter PHP in a block. It's less secure, trickier to maintain (no version control!) and more difficult to debug if something breaks.